# Alternative for the core statistics module that also includes pages created using Views?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I want to make a block, which shows the title of 10 most visited contents of my site and then display those as an ordered list.

My **pages are created using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module**. I tried to get it done using the core `Statistics` module. But it lists only Articles, Basic pages, or Content types which we have created. But it doesn't list pages which are created by Views.

Is there any contributed module for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Here are some reports you get from it:

> - View pages that have recently been visited.
> - View pages that have been hit frequently.
> - View pages count per month, day of month, day of week, hour.
> - ...

Especially these reports should be what you're looking for (it includes hits for paths corresponding to a view):

- [Top pages](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/top_pages.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Title, Path and nr of Hits). Here is an example of this report:

  [image]
- [Recent hits](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/recent_hits.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Date of visit, Title, Path and User ID of the visitor). Here is an example of this report:

  [image]

  If you follow any of the "details" links in the example above, you'll get something that looks as in this example:

  [image]

Checkout the above (source) links to get an idea of which data are available.

The demo site contains [some sample reports (charts)](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors) available to anonymous users also. Any visits to a Views related path will be reported in the **Recent hits** module. This demo site also shows some additional blocks with reports also created by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module module.

You may also want to look at the [visitors_schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/visitors.install?h=7.x-2.x#n37) to get an idea of the data that actually get logged (recorded) by this module.

In case it's not a perfect fit, it's probably a very good starting point for some custom reporting. Either via a custom module that would simply have to query the data maintained by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Or via a straight forward custom report created with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module,
and co-maintainer of the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Hi Pierre, Very thanks for the answer. This is good module. But I would like to explain what my site need is. Lets say I prepare 10 pages using views module, and putting all them in menu bar as some title i.e. page-1, page-2.......page-10. Now suppose if page-8 viewed most then page-6, then page-1, so my Block needs to display just title of this page which is  like list.....Page-8, Page-6, Page-1.....Thanks

Comment: I further extended my answer, which I think should help to address your comment above. Let me know ...